# extended classes from jar does not work

Tags: java, jar, xmlbeans

I've a project in which xmlbeans 2.6.0 jars are referenced and are added to the classpath. I create a class similar to the below:

```
import org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaType;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase;

public class Test3 extends XmlComplexContentImpl {

    public Test3(SchemaType type) {
        super(type);
    }

    public void hello() {

        // The below method is present in XmlObjectBase which is extended by XmlComplexContentImpl
        // XmlObjectBase and XmlComplexContentImpl are part of jar
        generatedSetterHelperImpl(null, null, 0, (short)2);

    }

}
```

And when I create an instance of Test3 and call `hello()` method, an error `NoSuchMethodError` is thrown. It basically does not lookup the extended class for the method instead searches for the method in Test3.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.voxify.vui.action.Test3.generatedSetterHelperImpl(Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;IS)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

These errors generally arise from jar version conflict. You may have different jar version at compile time and run time.One way to quickly check that is to remove the jar where you think it is getting referred to. That way you might find the different version of the same jar in classpath which is actually getting loaded.

Comment: Thanks! There are dependent projects for this project. And in the them, xmlbeans jars are present but with the same version

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had two version of the same jar, xmlbeans-2.6.0 and xmlbeans-2.3.0 in my application path.  Once I remove the oldest, the program runs.